# Style :before on hover

Tags: css

I have a button:

```
.button{
 background-color:red;
 color:#fff;
 width:70px;
}
.button:before{
 min-width:0px;
 content: attr(data-number);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="button" data-number="5"><a href="javascript:;">button</a></div>
```

my problem is, I want the content number to be black when user put mouse hover `button` text.
I try:

```
.button:hover .button:before{
 color:#000;
}
```

but it is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/733ogk3f/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `:hover` and `:before` at the same time as:

```
.button:hover:before {
    color:#000;
}
```

Such CSS selector as `.button:hover .button:before` points to `.button` inside `.button`. But it's not your case.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.button:hover::before{
    color:#000;
}
```

You need to select both `:hover` and `::before`

Comment: Yeah, I want the white text (letter 5) to become black! thank you!

Comment: Ok, I've changed my answer then to be specific to that.